# Can I provide app redemption codes without publishing?

Tags: app-store-connect, b2b, iosdeployment

my company wants to distribute out app via redemption codes at an expo. We do not want the app to be public, and we need more than 100 codes. We are enrolled in both programs, and the most recent build is approved on itunes connect but not released. What steps can I take to achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get more than 100 promo codes for an app's version. You would need to update your app. For each version you get another 100 promo codes.

> You can request up to **100 promo codes for every version** of each platform of your app, or for your in-app purchases.
>
> With in-app purchase promo codes, users can download your app (if the price of the app set to free) and redeem the code for the in-app purchase item. Codes can even be used before your app is available on the App Store. You can provide up to 100 promo codes for each in-app purchase item, with a **limit of 1,000 total in-app purchase codes per app every six months** (resetting on January 1 and July 1). These codes are for non-commercial use and expire 28 days after they were requested.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link for detail instructions in creating promo codes.  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ProvidingPromoCodes.html

Codes can be used if **the version’s status must be Ready for Sale or Pending Developer Release. For in-app purchases, the state must be Approved or it won't appear as an option.**

In your case since app is approved by apple but pending developer release, you can use them for selective group.

Comment: Thank you but this does not answer the question. I need a way to get more than 100.

Comment: @McCadi - You can provide up to 100 promo codes for each in-app purchase item, with a limit of 1,000 total in-app purchase codes per app every six months (resetting on January 1 and July 1)